# Как правильно логировать работу приложения?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Иногда хочется знать, что происходит с приложением в релизном варианте в боевом режиме под руками безжалостного пользователя... Возникают ошибки в приложении, а польз ователь ничего не может сказать, что он нажимал, куда мышкой водил, и какой текст набирал - как всегда оно само сломалось. Возникает вопрос, как правильно построить логику программы, чтобы было удобно логировать ее работу, а также удобно внедрять в готовые продукты. Сам экспериментирую на небольших программных продуктах (до 3000 строчек функционального кода на C#, но на мой взгляд пока не нашел идеального варианта). Из того что пробовал:

- Создание класса, со свойствами (для управления уровнем логирования, предварительных настроек). Класс инициализируется при старте программы, после из основного модуля ему передаются настройки, вызывается из основного модуля функция записи в лог. Сам класс решает писать ему только в свой список, в контрол, который ему передали, в файл. Нужно ли вообще писать это сообщение в зависимости от уровня логирования. ну и прочие фишечки рюшечки. недостаток того, что в каждой функции, которую хочется залогировать, приходится явно вызывать этот класс, требуется точно быть уверенным что он создан (ну это обходится созданием функции записи в лог, с проверкой созданного класса логирования и отловлей эксепшенов от него). Недостаточно глубоко в классы можно залезть.
- Создание класса приемерно такого же, за тем исключением, что запись вызывается путем отловли пользовательского сообщения на уровне приложения. Проблемы примерно такие же. Приходится каждое действие отдельно описывать в момент выполнения действий, что не удобно и загромождает полезный код программы. НУ и в случае падения программы, в лог данные могут не попасть, т.к. приложение не примет сообщение.
- Тоже что и выше, только ловля сообщений происходит в отдельном потоке - пробелемы схода - более менее серьезное падение программы приводит к повисанию потока, который соответственно сообщение не примет и не запишет в лог.
- Вариант с отдельным процессом для меня видится не лучшим вариантом. т.к. это лишние проблемы и не нужные вещи, к которым я крайне плохо отношусь.

ИТОГО: Интересуют два момента:

1. как писать в лог, не загромождая полезный код программы и не усложняя его чтение.
2. как зафиксировать наиболее подробный лог, даже в случае падения, повисания программы.

Comment: _"сообщение не примет и не запишет в лог"_ -- если использовать etw  и perfview, то все записывается. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479041/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По общему вопросу.
Log4Net - почти стандарт (не нужно изобретать велосипед)
Может помочь AOP (типа PostSharp), в таком случае не нужно "коверкать" исходный код.

> 1. как писать в лог, не загромождая полезный код программы и не усложняя его чтение.

Писать в отдельный лог-файл или другое хранилище, очевидно же. Ну или в том же log4Net используются различные уровни записей.

> 1. как зафиксировать наиболее подробный лог, даже в случае падения, повисания программы.

Наиболее подробный лог получается, как ни странно, при логировании исключения. Во-первых что-бы иметь актуальный стек, ошибка не должна скрываться во "внутренних деталях реализации" и дойти до глобального обработчика ошибок в своем начальном виде или со своими дополнениями. Во-вторых, должна обработаться либо с записью в какое-то хранилище, либо передана по почте разработчикам и прочее.

Comment: Попробовал - но неудобно:
1. Нужно тащить длл. Соответственно корректно подключать ее динамически, чтобы не было проблем при старте программы.
2. Идея интересная, наверное стоит сделать нечто свое, но заложить вышеописанную схему логирования... Конечно получается изобретение велосипеда - зато заточенного под свою пятую точку =)

Comment: В общем остановился на логировании исключений... трудоемко конечно получилось, пришлось создать на каждый пук по исключению, но зато наглядно и все можно отследить. подумываю о введении кодов ошибок, чтобы не создавать разные исключения на схожие проблемы.