# Как логировать работу программы с помощью ETW?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, логирование

Информация о работе .NET выводится в ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) и ее можно получить с помощью программы PerfView.
Как из приложения выводить свою информацию в ETW?
И возможно ли выводить 100 тыс. сообщений в секунду?

Answer (score 6):

ETW позволяет выводить до [500 тыс.](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Logging) сообщений в секунду с минимальными затратами.

Например, надо в ETW выводить уведомления о ходе выполнения, а также информацию о начале и завершении какой-то активности.
Для этого надо определить класс, производный от [EventSource](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource).

```
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;

[EventSource(Name = "MyApp")]
class MyAppEvent : EventSource {
    public static MyAppEvent Log = new MyAppEvent();

    [Event(1)]   // уведомление о ходе выполнения
    public void Progress(int v, string msg) { WriteEvent(1, v, msg); }

    [Event(2, Opcode = EventOpcode.Start)]  // начало активности
    public void StartAction(int id) { WriteEvent(2, id); }

    [Event(3, Opcode = EventOpcode.Stop)]   // завершение активности 
    public void StopAction(int id) { WriteEvent(3, id); }
}
```

для вывода в ETW пишем

```
partial class MainWindow : Window {
   public MainWindow() {
      var log = MyAppEvent.Log;
      ...
      log.Start(1);
      log.Progress(1, "ok");
      log.Stop(1);
```

Компилируем и из командной строки запускаем [PerView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567)

```
> PerfView /OnlyProviders=*MyApp run WpfApplication.exe
```

В результате создается `PerfViewData.etl.zip`, в котором находится файл `PerfViewData.etl` - его можно открыть в PerfView и посмотреть информацию, например, по вызовам Start.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А разве нельзя отконфигурировать стандартный `Debug.Write`, чтобы он писал в ETW? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/475214/10105

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33714/discussion-on-answer-by-stack------etw).