# Правильный механизм обработки исключений

Tags: исключения

Как правильно "работать" с исключениями?

Я поступаю так: если программа не может дальше работать корректно из-за какой-то ошибки (передана пустая ссылка на объект, или данные повреждены), я бросаю исключение. Встает вопрос: где обрабатывать эти исключения и как?

Например, если была передана нулевая ссылка на объект и бросается `ArgumentNullException`, то пользователю такие сообщения не стоит показывать, а стоит вывести что-то типа "В приложении ошибка, оно сейчас закроется, ... .". Но если пользователь указал неверный путь к файлу или ввел некорректные данные, ему стоит сообщить это, в данном случае нужно создавать исключения специального типа (наследовать `Exception`...) и отлавливать их в одном месте?

Таким образом, если исключение не является специальным, то мы говорим, что ошибка случилась не по вине пользователя, а если специальным (или мы знаем, что это исключение могло возникнуть только по вине пользователя), то мы "даем пользователю второй шанс" и говорим ему об этом?

Comment: _"если программа не может дальше работать ...  где обрабатывать эти исключения"_ -- если не может работать, то значит надо [fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast). а исключение надо записать в лог, например, с помощью EventSource -- может до 500 тыс./сек. записей в лог. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479042/196972)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конкретно по вашему списку:

- Передана пустая ссылка на объект — это баг в программе. Исправьте, и не допускайте такого никогда в production-коде.
- Данные повреждены — если это внешние данные (прочитанные из файла), это исключение, вызванное внешними условиями. Ловите его и реагируйте соответственно.
- Пользователь указал неверный путь к файлу — это вовсе не исключение. Пользователь ввёл строку, и то, что это строка может не оказаться валидным именем файла, или с этим файлом что-то не так — ожидаемый поворот событий. Если проверить ввод пользователя на правильность не получается без исключений, отлавливайте их как можно раньше.

---

Исключения можно условно разделить на 4 типа.

**Фатальные** исключения. Это исключения, которые вызваны не вашей ошибкой, а внешними проблемами. Ошибка при загрузке программы с диска, поток остановлен внешним процессом. Вы ничего не можете сделать, просто дайте процессу спокойно умереть. Выхода из этой ситуации для вашего кода просто нет.

Ваша программа в этот момент находится в каком-то непонятном состоянии, попытка «всё исправить» может вполне привести к потере данных и проблемам, более серьёзным чем один креш приложения.

**Глупые** исключения. Это исключения, вызванные исключительно багами в вашем коде. Индекс вне разрешённого диапазона, деление на ноль, обращение по нулевому указателю. Это всё проблемы, которые не возникли бы, если бы код был запрограммирован правильно. Вы не должны их ловить и пытаться замазать баги, вы должны просто исправить их.

**Досаждающие** исключения. Эти исключения — результат неудачных, неподходящих архитектурных решений. Они выбрасываются в ситуации, которую сложно назвать *исключительной*, но вы всё же должны всё время ловить и обрабатывать их. Классический пример — функция `int.Parse`, которая бросает исключение, если строка-аргумент не является целым числом. В большинстве случаев эта функция используется для преобразования строк, введённым *пользователем*, которые с хорошими шансами будут неправильными. Хуже того, нет никакого хорошего пути определить заранее, является ли строка реально числом, не дублируя фактически логику `int.Parse`.

(По этой причине, кстати, в C# появилась и функция `int.TryParse`. А в Java её до сих пор нет, приходится-таки ловить исключение, бросаемое `Integer.parseInt`.)

И наконец, **внешние** исключения — это исключения, которые не являются следствием неверного дизайна, а скорее отражают несоответствие реального мира упрощённой логике программистов. Например, вы пытаетесь открыть файл, но файла может не оказаться по тому имени, которое вы указали. (Даже если вы проверите существование файла, в момент времени между проверкой и открытием файла он вполне может исчезнуть — например, юзер может вынуть диск из CD-драйва.) Исключения здесь не избежать в силу того, что фактически успешность нашего действия зависит от причин из внешнего мира, не находящихся под нашим контролем.

---

Итак, суммируя:

- Не пытайтесь ловить фатальные исключения. Вы уже ничего не можете сделать, а если попытаетесь, можете сделать только хуже.
- Исправляйте ошибки в коде, чтобы исключить глупые исключения. В готовом коде не должно быть ошибок индексации, вам должно быть стыдно даже думать ловить такие исключения.
- Пытайтесь избежать досаждающих исключений. Если можно, вызывайте версию методов, не приводящих к ним.
- Всегда ловите внешние исключения. Вы не сможете предотвратить их проверками, просто попробуйте выполнить операцию, и будьте готовы к возможным исключениям.

---

(Сокращённый пересказ [этой статьи](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).)

Comment: выходит все взаимодействия с внешним окружением (файловая система, удаленные сервисы ..) все это нужно делать в try-catch блоке ?

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev: По сути — да, любое из них может завершиться аварийно. С другой стороны, нет смысла заключать в try/catch _каждую_ операцию, имеет смысл поместить try/catch на как можно более внешний уровень, на котором программа всё ещё будет правильной.

Answer (score 3):

По хорошему, неверные действия пользователя должны предотвращаться, а не обрабатываться в качестве исключений.

Например,

> если пользователь указал неверный путь к файлу

Всегда можно проверить существование файла и, если его нет, выдать соответствующее уведомление и повторно вызвать диалог открытия файла.

Что касается собственных классов исключений. Их имеет смысл создавать, если для данного некорректного действия нет подходящего класса исключений среди уже существующих и Вы хотите, если так можно выразиться, конкретизировать возникающую в этом случае ошибку. При таком подходе, собственные классы исключений, это хороший тон.

Comment: А есть ли смысл делать так: мы пишем приложение состоящее из разных модулей, позже мы возможно захотим переиспользовать какой-нибудь (или кто-то другой). Например модуль чтения данных из файла, в нем мы перехватываем возникающие исключения и бросаем новое (например  LoadFileException когда формат данных не подходит) таким образом клиенты нашего api получат не какой-нибудь indexOutOfRangeException а более понятное сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: Дело в том, что ответ на этот вопрос уже был дан в основном ответе (извините за тавтологию) в последнем абзаце. Относительно "более понятных сообщений". Нужную информацию при необходимости можно вывести и непосредственно при обработке исключения.

Answer (score 2):

Исключения - довольно исключительный вопрос, который следует рассматривать в связке с определенным языком программирования.

Дальнейший текст - применительно к C++

Так как обработка исключения, а также подготовка окружения для входа в очередной `try` несут дополнительные расходы, есть непраздные рекомендации об отказе от исключений в критическом по времени выполнения коде.

С другой стороны, в соответствии со стандартом, огромное количество примитивов C++, в том числе и операторы вроде `new`, информируют об ошибке только посредством исключений. Отсюда следует, что от отлавливания исключений просто так сбежать не выйдет.

Итак, можно выработать следующую стратегию.

1. Для некритичного по производительности кода, возможен полный перевод на информирование об ошибках посредством исключений. Это позволит во-первых, полностью задействовать RAII, во вторых, получить довольно таки грамотные сигнатуры методов - метод или возвращает результат, либо выбрасывает нужное исключение. Методы, которые возвращают `bool` как признак успеха, или даже какой либо `enum` с признаком состояния, можно успешно выбросить. Механизм структурной, иерархической, обработки ошибок при таком подходе работает наиболее полно. Минусы - требуется вдумчивая работа над классами-исключениями и четкое следование RAII, возможна посадка производительности, возможно облегчение декомпиляции программы.
2. Для критичного кода, стоит отказаться от исключений и писать в так 
   называемом exception-safe стиле, что тоже достаточно сложно.
3. Не забывать ловить все исключения до выхода из деструктора.

Предупреждение ошибок, о котором написали выше, практически никогда не работает - есть ведь не ненулевая вероятность, что пользователь дернет флешку ровно в тот момент, когда вы уже заглянули в хрустальный шар и убедились, что все будет хорошо.

От себя добавлю, что C++ без исключений - примерно как велосипед без педалей, потому как нормального RAII тогда не видать.