# C# Получить среднее время выполнения 10 операций

Tags: c#, datetime

В коде выполняются 10 операций:

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
Foo();
var end = DateTime.Now;
```

Задача: сложить разницу end - start всех 10 операций и получить среднее значение

Сделал так, но результаты явно неверные:

```
var time = result.Aggregate(time, (current, finalResult) => current + (end - start));
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(time.Ticks / Count).ToString("mm:ss.fff"));
```

Comment: Так не делается. Обычно запускают счетчик, потом в цикле запускают исполнение тестируемых комманд, и по завершению счетчика производят подсчет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам стоит использовать Stopwwatch вместо DateTime. Stopwatch как раз предназначен для точного измерения промежутков времени, в частности, времени выполнения участков кода. Во-первых, он имеет бОльшую, нежели DateTime, разрешающую способность (DateTime не сможет корректно измерить короткие промежутки порядка одной миллисекунды и меньше), во-вторых, пусть даже теоретически, но возможна ситуация, когда во время выполнения вашего кода произойдёт какая-либо коррекция времени системы, что чревато неправильным измерением (скажем, произойдёт перевод времени). Плюс оперировать с миллисекундами и тиками системного таймера проще, чем с датами и TimeSpan'ами.

Для решения вашей задачи поступите самым простым способом - 10 раз измерьте время выполнения кода в миллисекундах или тиках, сложите и поделите на 10, элементарная арифметика

Comment: Спасибо, а получить среднее значениt используя Stopwatch?

Comment: @tCode опишите конкртетнее, как именно происходит выполнение этих десяти операций

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
result = new Foo();
}

Foo возвращает класс с EndTime и StartTime, в которые записывает данные

Answer (score 7):

В Windows есть [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) -- [таймер высокого разрешения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx).
В .NET есть его обертка -- **Stopwatch** (исходный код [тут](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,ceb0ba9cc88de82e)).

Если надо получить среднее время выполнения метода/функции, то пишем так

```
long Tester(int count, Action fn) {
   var s = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) fn();
   s.Stop();
   return s.ElapsedTicks;
}

var ticks = Tester(10, () => Foo());    // тестируем Foo
var avg = ticks / 10;   // среднее
var ms = TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks).Milliseconds;
```

---

**UPDATE**

Если результаты тестов, а также разную отладочную информацию 
(до 500 тыс. сообщений в секунду) надо выводить в лог, то можно использовать [ETW](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479041).

Comment: Да, спасибо, решил задачу с помощью Stopwatch