# Как точно измерить время выполнения операции С#?

Tags: c#

Для лабораторной работы нужно измерить время выполнения нескольких операций.
Код:

```
StartTime = Environment.TickCount;
for (int i = 0; i < 2499; i++)
{
    LQL.Rem();
}
ResultTime = Environment.TickCount - StartTime;

public class LinkedStackLarge
{
    LinkedList<LargeData> _LinkedStack = new LinkedList<LargeData>();
    public LargeData Rem()
    {
        LargeData data = _LinkedStack.Last();
        _LinkedStack.RemoveFirst();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Код работает, но `ResultTime` в конце равно `0`. Это нормально?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону Stopwatch. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 17):

Измерение времени операции — на самом деле сложный момент, тут есть много тонкостей.

Первая тонкость — JIT warm-up: когда метод исполняется в первый раз, происходит JIT-компиляция кода этого метода. Поэтому чтобы получить правильное время, необходимо перед измерением выполнить измеряемый код «вхолостую».

Следующая тонкость: при запуске из-под отладчика JIT-компилятор даже в Release mode оптимизирует ваш код не очень агрессивно, чтобы в отладчике всё ещё были видны нужные переменные и стек вызовов. Запускайте ваши тесты из-под командной строки вне Visual Studio.

Следующая тонкость: если ваш измеряемый метод не производит побочных эффектов и не возвращает значения, или возвращаемое значение игнорируется, то оптимизатор может выбросить его вызов. Поэтому обязательно выводите возвращаемое значение на экран.

Следующая тонкость: метод может быть *очень* быстрым, и сумманое время выполнения может оказаться в пределах разрешения используемого вами таймера. Для того, чтобы реально измерить его скорость, нужно выполнить его `N` раз, и суммарное время поделить на `N`. Число `N` проще всего подобрать экспериментально.

Следующая тонкость: различные таймеры имеют различное разрешение. Лучше брать более точный таймер. Я, например, использую `Stopwatch`, о котором говорит @Denis Bubnov в своём ответе.

Следующая тонкость: выполнение может быть прервано различными внешними событиями. Например, системный планировщик потоков может отобрать квант времени у вашего потока, в результате измеренное значение будет больше, чем реальное время пробега метода. Или сборщик мусора может заморозить ваш поток. Поэтому имеет смысл проводить измерения несколько раз, и отбрасывать результаты, которые статистически слишком далеко отстоят от среднего значения.

Следующая тонкость: различные системные кеши. Например, если ваш код читает файл, то после первого чтения файл окажется в кеше операционной системы, и последующие выполнения того же метода будут быстрее. Поэтому в таком случае каждая новая итерация должна читать новый файл.

---

Практически, учитывать эти штуки в своём коде каждый раз лень. Поэтому имеет смысл воспользоваться фреймворком для бенчмарков. Например, можно использовать [BenchmarkDotNet](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/index.htm). В этом случае ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Tester>();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Tester
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void Test()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2499; i++)
        {
            LQL.Rem();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что то мне кажется, вы путаете анализ производительности и изменение времени работы

Comment: @tym32167: А в чём отличие?

Comment: Измерение времени - это количество времени, которое прошло между 2 событиями. Анализ производительности - тестирование производительности кода. Из вопроса мне не совсем ясно, что хочет сделать автор.

Comment: @tym32167: Ну, автор говорит о лабораторной работе и измерении времени выполнения нескольких операций. Поэтому мне кажется, что я угадал со смыслом.

Comment: Да, скорее всего вы правы. Я просто изначально зашел сюда и хотел написать то же, что и вы (тоже использую эту либу). Но потом увидел заплюсованный ответ про изменение времени и решил почему то, что я неверно понял вопрос :)

Answer (score 14):

Используйте класс [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx). Он предоставляет набор методов и свойств, которые можно использовать для точного измерения затраченного времени.

```
var startTime = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (int i = 0; i < 2499; i++)
{
    LQL.Rem();
}

startTime.Stop();
var resultTime = startTime.Elapsed;

// elapsedTime - строка, которая будет содержать значение затраченного времени
string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}",
    resultTime.Hours, 
    resultTime.Minutes, 
    resultTime.Seconds,
    resultTime.Milliseconds);
```

Свойство [`Stopwatch.Elapsed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx) - получает общее затраченное время, измеренное текущим экземпляром.

Полезные ссылки:

- [C# Получить среднее время выполнения 10 операций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486705/189339)
- [Stopwatch vs. using System.DateTime.Now for timing events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2923349/5275890)
- [Is DateTime.Now the best way to measure a function's performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648/5275890)
- [Environment.TickCount vs DateTime.Now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/243357/5275890)

### Примечание:

> [`Environment.TickCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx) основана на [`GetTickCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408.aspx) функции WinAPI.
>   Разрешение функции `GetTickCount` ограничено разрешением системного
>   таймера, который обычно находится в диапазоне от 10 миллисекунд до 16
>   миллисекунд. Функция дает результат в миллисекундах, но фактическая
>   точность составляет не более 16 миллисекунд. Таким образом, для
>   коротких интервалов времени менее 16 миллисекунд вы получите 0.

В этом ответе хорошо и понятно написано про `Environment.TickCount`, `DateTime.Ticks` и `Stopwatch` (правда на английском языке): [Environment.TickCount vs DateTime.Now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8865560/5275890)

Comment: Был бы рад услышать, а почему минус-то? Очень интересно, может нужно что-то исправить в ответе.